# Use extracted parameter as variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, variables, routes

I'm a complete novice to batch files, I just want to accomplish one thing 
get interface ip for a certain routed ip and use this same interface for a list of ip's.

looking around I managed to extract the interface ip, but can't get around to use it subsequently in the code for the routing part.

with the following code you get the idea

```
set _netstat_cmd=netstat -nr
FOR /F "tokens=5" %G IN ('%_netstat_cmd% ^|find "10.11.3.31"') Do echo Result is %G
set rslt=%G

route delete 10.11.30.188 
route delete 10.11.30.103
route delete 10.11.30.68
route delete 10.11.0.140
route delete 10.11.30.63

route add 10.11.30.188 mask 255.255.255.255 %rslt% METRIC 1
route add 10.11.30.103 mask 255.255.255.255 %rslt% METRIC 1
route add 10.11.30.68 mask 255.255.255.255 %rslt% METRIC 1
route add 10.11.0.140 mask 255.255.255.255 %rslt% METRIC 1
route add 10.11.30.63 mask 255.255.255.255 %rslt% METRIC 1
```

what am i missing? 
i did some trial and error but hard to understand the underlying rules...

Comment: 1. You're missing a `%` at the end of `set rslt=%G`. 2. I don't think that `G` is known at this point in your script. 3. You're right about finding it hard to understand the underlying rules; Windows shell is notoriously known for not having any rules; if you can "afford it", I recommend to do it in Python or in NodeJS.

Comment: batch files use `%%G` where cmdline uses `%G` additionally.. something seems off, you are looking to this for each result containing `10.11.3.31` but you set result after the loop, so this will only hapen once for `rslt` so enclose your do stuff in code block.. `do (stuff)`

Comment: `… Do (echo Result is %G&set rslt=%G)` **and** use `%%G` in a batch-file instead of `%G` used in  `cmd` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working on `cmdline` we use single `%`, however inside of a batch file You need to double `%` for token variables like: `%%G`

Also in order to run for each result you need a code block so we can do it without the need for `delayedexpansion` if we do not set a variable.

```
@echo off
set "_netstat_cmd=netstat -nr"
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%G IN ('%_netstat_cmd% ^|find "10.11.3.31"') Do (
    echo Result is %%G
    route delete 10.11.30.188 
    route delete 10.11.30.103
    route delete 10.11.30.68
    route delete 10.11.0.140
    route delete 10.11.30.63

    route add 10.11.30.188 mask 255.255.255.255 %%G METRIC 1
    route add 10.11.30.103 mask 255.255.255.255 %%G METRIC 1
    route add 10.11.30.68 mask 255.255.255.255 %%G METRIC 1
    route add 10.11.0.140 mask 255.255.255.255 %%G METRIC 1
    route add 10.11.30.63 mask 255.255.255.255 %%G METRIC 1
)
```

If however you really want to set a variable, you need `delayedexpansion` to expand the variables inside the code block.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_netstat_cmd=netstat -nr"
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%G IN ('%_netstat_cmd% ^|find "10.11.3.31"') Do (
    echo Result is %%G
    set "rslt=%%G"
    route delete 10.11.30.188 
    route delete 10.11.30.103
    route delete 10.11.30.68
    route delete 10.11.0.140
    route delete 10.11.30.63

    route add 10.11.30.188 mask 255.255.255.255 !rslt! METRIC 1
    route add 10.11.30.103 mask 255.255.255.255 !rslt! METRIC 1
    route add 10.11.30.68 mask 255.255.255.255 !rslt! METRIC 1
    route add 10.11.0.140 mask 255.255.255.255 !rslt! METRIC 1
    route add 10.11.30.63 mask 255.255.255.255 !rslt! METRIC 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm -- and I think I do now understand a little more how batch file works. Thank you to all other comments! appreciate